# Session timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem in creating Session. Session.Timeout doesn't work.
This is my code 
`Session["UID"] = Uid;`
`Session["UserName"] = UserName;`
`Session.Timeout = 10;` // ?not responding

Session.Timeout occurs after 3 or 4 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You should set session timeout in the web.config file like this:

```
<sessionState
   mode="InProc"
   cookieless="AutoDetect"
   timeout="10" />
```

Taken from here: [MSDN on the session state element in web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: it did not help, I change IIS Session Satte ASP.NET_SessionId Timeout, but  no result

Answer (score 0):

try b making changes in your web.config file instead of the cs file.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState 
      mode="InProc"
      cookieless="true"
      timeout="30" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

read more about it at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)